# Creating a random key using audio signal

Tags: java, security, audio, random, passwords

We know that "random" numbers that we generate in our code are really pseudo-random.  They, in the case of Java, default to using the timestamp as a random seed and every random number produced after that is deterministically created from that point forward.

If you use random numbers to generate a password and a malicious party knows what day you generated that password, they would only have to iterate through each millisecond in that day.  That would be 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 86.4 million. This is not a very big number of guesses for a sophisticated party.  Edward Snowden famously warned, "assume your adversary is capable of one trillion guesses per second."

The problem is, how do we produce truly random numbers?  What I'd like is to sample 16-bit audio from the microphone of my laptop and use the least-significant 8 bits of two samples to form a seed.  The idea here is that the least-significant part of an audio signal is where the noise is carried.  For example, here are a few two-byte values from a 16-bit sample recorded in a relatively quite place:

```
0,19
0,38
0,-49
1,93
1,-29
1,-80
```

You can see that the most significant byte is 0 or 1, which means the wave being recorded was barely registering.  On the other hand, the least significant byte value is jumping all over the place.  That's a fertile ground for random seeds!

The specific question for this post being:  How can we produce a random 32-character password using the noise signal producedby the real-world noise around us.

Comment: Self-answered questions should take the form of a specific _question_, not an open-ended project.

Comment: Or simply use `Math.random()` or if you want "secure" `""+Math.random()+Math.random()+Math.random()` :D

Answer (score 0):

This has been a nice afternoon project!  Here's a utility class with static methods that can produce an array of random ints or a random string of desired length.

[Gist link.](https://gist.github.com/brianrisk/c38ebc71c625533205f19b3023f8285b)

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class RandomFromAudio {

    public static final String ALLOWED_CHARACTERS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    // Demonstrating the methods
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandomKey(32));
    }

    public static String getRandomKey(int keyLength) {
        int [] randomInts = getRandomIntArray(keyLength);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int randomInt: randomInts) {
            char randomChar = ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.charAt(randomInt % ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.length());
            stringBuilder.append(randomChar);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static int [] getRandomIntArray(int desiredLength) {
        int [] out = null;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
        TargetDataLine microphone;
        try {
            out = new int[desiredLength];
            byte[] data = new byte[2];

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            microphone.open(format);
            microphone.start();

            // my microphone seems to need to "warm up".
            // It gets a lot of low signal at the beginning producing a lot of low numbers.
            // This loop reads signal until it shows that a decently high value can be reached.
            while (data[1] < 100) {
                microphone.read(data, 0, data.length);
            }
            byte [] leastSig = new byte[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < desiredLength * 2; i++) {
                microphone.read(data, 0, data.length);
                // saving the least significant byte
                leastSig[i % 2] = data[1];
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    // combining the bytes into an int
                    out[(i + 1) / 2 - 1] = leastSig[0]<<8 &0xFF00 | leastSig[1]&0xFF;
                }
            }
            microphone.close();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Running a few times (for me) produced:

```
hqctXiTiV67iI2JAXrcU0vzGhxEBDN2R
ViCSGxahmI51mXfBIV7INo9vu3ZuKNDi
9oTl1Meer59Y69yxNRTa0Dv3pWNywZFY
zfLrh9ZU8oNLg43M1D1ZzcoSxJ4X1HOQ
dlhliKxM4tAhr8uoCOtdRsmwARIE6Gjb
```